# How to test the app in iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios-simulator

I am writing a iPhone program and testing it in the iPhone simulator. Can I test the app in the iPad simulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes! To do this I can open the iPhone Simulator and from Hardware menu, choose Device then iPad.
If you have a big screen you can see the iPad Simulator more little then normal, scaled at 50%.
If you want to see it at 100%, go to Window menu, choose Scale and then select 100%.
Now return in Xcode and Build you application :)

Comment: @Matthew, thank you for your reply. But I am not understand what you are talking about of the steps. Would you mind post some screen shot for me?

Comment: @MarkSiu oh yeah, I can! But for me, this menu are in Italian...
This is screen one: http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/5277/schermata20100820a10472.png and this is screen two: http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/7287/schermata20100820a10473.png

;)

Comment: @Matthew, thank you for your reply. I find the problem is about my Xcode version. When I click the iPhone simulator and the hardware, it does have the iPad. Would you mind to tell me what version are you using?

Comment: @MarkSiu yes, I have Xcode 3.2.3 with iPhone SDK 4.0... If I memory well, iPad Simulator is available from iPhone SDK 3.2.

Comment: @Matthew, I am using the Xcode 3.1.4, I guess it does not have the iPad. Thank you.

Comment: @MarkSiu You're welcome, however I advise you to upgrade your SDK at 4.0... Now on developer site is available iPhone SDK 4.0.2 :)